# Jquery jtable options fails in IIS server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iis, jquery-jtable

```
TypeID: {
                            title: 'Type',
                            width: '30%',
                            inputClass: 'validate[required]',
                            options: <%= DisplayCribOptions() %>
                        },
                        Number: {
                            title: 'Crib No',
                            width: '20%'                            
                        },
                        Name: {
                            title: 'Name',
                            width: '20%',
                            listClass: 'align'
                        },
                        ConfigStacks:{
                            title:  'Configurable Stacks',
                            width: '30%',
                            dependsOn:'TypeID',
                            listClass: 'centerCol',

                            options: function (data)
                            {
                                if (data.source  == 'list')
                                {

                               //return ['0','1','2','3','4','5'] ;
                                   return '/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0';
                                }

                                return '/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID='+data.dependedValues.TypeID;
         }
```

The corresponding code bind  is

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
     public static object GetBinOptions(int TypeID)
            {
                try
                {
                    int[] configBins = new int[6]; ;

                    if (TypeID == 2)
                        configBins = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
                    else if ((TypeID == 3) || (TypeID == 4))
                        configBins = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                    else if (TypeID == 1)
                        configBins = new int[] { 0 };
                    else
                        configBins = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                    return new { Result = "OK", Options = configBins };

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
                }
            }
```

When i run this code in .net development server it works fine.But when i host this in IIS server i am getting 500 internal server error.

the only difference i found in local system and IIS is

```
Request URL:http://localhost:49196/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=3
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Connection:Close
Content-Length:45
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 07 Aug 2015 00:36:21 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

From IIS server

```
Request URL:http://net30.aaa.net/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:75
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 07 Aug 2015 00:39:09 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
```

The Response header Content_Type is different in both case.Also the content-Length is also different.

http://net30.aaa.net/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0  is sending 5 times if the options has 5 values.If the option has 3 values then the request is sending 3 times. That's how the Content-Length is different in  IIS.

Does anybody know the reason behind this.Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

I found that the  project is deployed on AZX folder.So for calling the options the URL should  be http://net30.aaa.net/AZX/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0  instead of  http://net30.aaa.net/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0   .All other link are same(http://net30.aaa.net/AZX/***.aspx) except this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making the options URL  the absolute url(http://net30.aaa/AZX/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0)`
Instead of hard coding i defined the domain in web.config .

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="domain" value="'http://net30.aaa/AZX'"/> <!-- (add the single quotes) -->

</configuration>
  </appSettings>
```

Read this value in page load  and pass it into the options

```
    public partial class Cribs : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      public string appdomain;
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
     appdomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"].ToString();
      }
    }
```

In the jtable

```
     ConfigStacks:{
                                title:  'Configurable Stacks',
                                width: '30%',
                                dependsOn:'TypeID',
                                listClass: 'centerCol',

                                options: function (data)
                                {
                                    if (data.source  == 'list')
                                    {


                                        return <%=appdomain%> +'/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID=0';
                                    }

                                      return  <%=appdomain%> +'/Cribs.aspx/GetBinOptions?TypeID='+data.dependedValues.TypeID;
                               }
                      }
```